# Double Implicit Conversion in C++

Tags: c++

I want to create a class that can be intialized by an integer and a class that can be initialized by this first class so that it can also be initialized with an integer.

```
class class1 {
    int n;
    class1(int i) {
      n = i;
    }
};

class class2 {
    class1 n = 0;
    class2(class1 i) {
      n = i;
    }
};

int main() {
    class2 n = 2; //Doesn't work
    class2 n = (class1) 2; //Does work
}
```

Comment: The compiler is only allowed to do one implicit conversion.

Comment: `class2 n {2};` works

Comment: You neglected to mention what your question is. You might see only one possible question coming from this setup, but do you really want to risk me coming up with a different one? (Actually, I see two potential "obvious" questions: one is "how" and one is "why".)

Comment: @JaMiT I think the question may well have been "Why doesn't it work" or "How can I make it work" ;). That said, I came here to know about the C++ semantics, that is, whether multiple implicit constructors can be chained.

Answer (score 5):

You are not allowed to do more than one implicit conversion, so you have to provide an `int` constructor for `class2`.

You can do this easily by adding a delegating constructor that calls the constructor that takes a `class1` argument:

```
class class2 {
  // ...
  class2(int i) : class2(class1{i}) {}
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9P57ad).

Also, assuming that the constructor taking a `class1` doesn't do anything more complicated than initialize `n`, you could simply do:

```
class class2 {
  // ...
  class2(int i) : n{i} {}
}
```